# range of comma separated numbers in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test if a string matches the following string format using regex.
It doesn't have to be these exact digits but any digits.

"1000-3000,5000-6000,6000-7000"

Below is what I have tried so far:

`/[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/g`

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean three numbers, the first from 1000 to 3000, the second from 5000 to 6000, and the final from 6000 to 7000, all separated by commas?

Comment: What is an example of something that matches?  That doesn't match?

Comment: @iteratedwall Comma separated number ranges. Any numbers.

Comment: @James it doesn't match. Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkhululincube/yhjxe43L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp matches a sequence of numbers, not ranges, because it doesn't match `-` between the numbers. `\d+-\d+` matches two numbers separated by `-`.

And you should anchor it if you want to test that the whole string matches, not a substring.

```
/^\d+-\d+(,\d+-\d+)*$/
```

Comment: Barmar I wan't to make sure the ranges have a hyphen (-) between

Comment: Doesn't my code do that with `\d+-\d+`?

Comment: Barmar It seem to be not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/mkhululincube/yhjxe43L/

Comment: @AmosEvange If you use the regexp cunstructor 1.) double the backslashes 2.) don't use delimiters - see [your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ra7mjztu/)

Comment: @AmosEvange Don't use `new RegExp()` unless you need to construct the regexp dynamically. There's no need for it here.